# Does my custom AppComponentFactory need to delegate to CoreComponentFactory, and if so how?

Tags: android, android-manifest, androidx

Looking at the "merged manifest" for a simple Android manifest file, if `androidx.core:core` is a dependency, you can see that AndroidX added its own `AppComponentFactory` to the `application` element, which is `androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory`. This seems to be a class that's internal to AndroidX (annotated with `@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX)`).

If I create my own `AppComponentFactory` and specify it explicitly in my manifest (`android:appComponentFactory`), it will replace the one defined by AndroidX, so that one won't be called. Will this have any impact? (I can't figure out exactly what `CoreComponentFactory` is doing, as it seems to be pluggable with components implementing an interface `CoreComponentFactory.CompatWrapped`, which itself is internal obviously.)

Also, if I wanted to delegate my custom implementation to AndroidX's one, is there any way for me to do this, given that it's an internal class within AndroidX?